# AdMob is working but getting blank page

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, admob

I have used adMob library for android. Sometimes getting blank page as like below screen shot. Can anyone explain what is the issue , and why its happen.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/adMobView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

   <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my code.

```
public void addIntegration(Context context, LinearLayout edtView) {
    LinearLayout mRlAddView = new LinearLayout(context);
        mRlAddView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        mRlAddView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        mRlAddView = edtView;
        AdView mAdView = new AdView(context);
        mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        mRlAddView.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        mAdView.setAdUnitId(context.getResources().getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id));
        mRlAddView.addView(mAdView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").build();
        mAdView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
```

Could any one tell me the solution for this issue.

Thanks.[image]

Comment: can you please put your logcat error ......

Comment: we don't have error. above image only displayed

Comment: just select in "Android Monitor" first drop down "NO FILTER" and in second drop down "ERROR" and run again you will get the error.

Comment: in this message occurring .......                                                   GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES EXCEPTION: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil
There is a problem with the Google Play Services library, which is required for Android Advertising ID support. The Google Play Services library should be integrated in any app shipping in the Play Store that uses analytics or advertising.

Comment: i am facing the issue once in a while

Comment: please follow the below link .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110142/discussion-between-sasikumar-and-sushil-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that no ad was actually loaded?

It's recommended to add a listener for ad events to your `AdView`s, so you could query and log ad lifecycle events: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner#ad_lifecycle_event_callbacks

Using the listener's calls you can get a good idea of what's actually going on:

```
public abstract class AdListener {
  public void onAdLoaded();
  public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode);
  public void onAdOpened();
  public void onAdClosed();
  public void onAdLeftApplication();
}
```